# How to add CORS header in Lambda/Node JS for API Gateway AWS

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to enable CORS header on my Lambda/Node JS function. I have tried to enable CORS in the API gateway but that us not working. Any idea's, My nodeJS/Lambda function code is as follows:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    if (event.httpMethod === 'GET') {
        return getData(event);
    }
};

const getData = event => {

    let data = {
        "home": [{
                "title": "John Doe title",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.", 
                "image": "image/example.jpg"
            }
        ],
        "about": [{
                "title": "John is the main part 1",
                "body": "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s.", 
                "image": "image/example.jpg"
            }
        ]
    };

    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)
    };
};
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its explained in the AWS docs:

[Enabling CORS Support for Lambda or HTTP Proxy Integrations](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-cors.html)

An example is the following:

```
return {
    'statusCode': 200,
    'headers': {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "http://localhost:8080",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Content-Type",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "OPTIONS,POST,GET"
    },
    'body': json.dumps(response)
}
```